# How to achieve rounded corners with a table

Tags: css

I have got this css for a table:

```
      .table_stats tr:last-child td:first-child{
        -moz-border-radius:0 0 0 6px;
        -webkit-border-radius:0 0 0 6px;
        border-radius:0 0 0 6px;
    }

   .table_stats tr:last-child td:last-child{
        -moz-border-radius:0 0 6px 0 ;
        -webkit-border-radius:0 0 6px 0 ;
        border-radius:0 0  6px 0 ;
    }
```

What I need is another border around it which is white in color.. is it possible to do with border stroke? and give it some width?

I also put a div around the table and gave it this css:

```
.table_stats{
    border-color: white;
   border-width:2px;
        -moz-border-radius: 6px 6px  ;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px 6px  ;
    border-radius: 6px 6px ;
}
```

Still didnt work.. no extra border around the table.

Html markup:

```
       <div class="table_stats">
      <table border="0" width="800px" style="margin-top: 100px;" cellspacing="0px" class="table_stats">
   </table>  
              </div>
```

Comment: `cellspacing="0px"` ? use `cellspacing="0"`

Comment: see the demo http://jsbin.com/utosif/1/edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify a `border-style` to see it in action.
Anyway, your table has a 100px top margin, try to remove it and add `display:inline-block;` to the div (or it will expand to 100%). That should do the trick

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gionaf/D54Wu/)

HTML:

```
<div class="table_stats">
<table border="0" width="800" cellspacing="0" class="table_stats">
</table>
</div>​
```

CSS:

```
div.table_stats{
    margin-top:100px;
    display:inline-block;
    border-color: white;
    border-width:2px;
    border-style:solid;
    -moz-border-radius: 6px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px ;
    border-radius: 6px ;
}
```

Comment: thanks... i came up with my solution     .table_stats_border{
        -moz-border-radius: 6px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
        -khtml-border-radius: 6px;
        border-radius: 6px;
           border: 5px solid white;
           margin-top: 100px;
           margin-right: 50px;
    }   . I think the problem was in the border style that i didnt put in